# Google sheets double query with selecting cell value as an explicit where condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have the following dataset:

```
Start day   End Day Product ID  Sells   Unites
01/11/2018  08/11/2018  Blue    DA_1000 $55,555.00  12
01/11/2018  08/11/2018  Red DA_1000 $1,321,321.00   55555
01/11/2018  08/11/2018  Blue    DA_1000 $444.00 11111
01/11/2018  08/11/2018  Green   DA_1000 $1,313,121.00   24
01/11/2018  08/11/2018  Aspire  DA_1001 $11.00  55555
09/11/2018  16/11/2018  Black   DA_1001 $786.13 49
09/11/2018  16/11/2018  Apple   DA_1001 $629.55 22
09/11/2018  16/11/2018  White   DA_1001 $0.39   1
17/11/2018  24/11/2018  Orange  DA_1002 $0.00   515413
17/11/2018  24/11/2018  Blue    DA_1002 $569.35 42
17/11/2018  24/11/2018  Red DA_1003 $315,154.00 40
25/11/2018  30/11/2018  White   DA_1003 $45,464,564.00  36
25/11/2018  30/11/2018  Black   DA_1003 $490.41 42
25/11/2018  30/11/2018  Vol DA_1004 $435.61 55
```

And I want to query from the products that have sells equal to=444, from this query I want to query again all of those that they're ID is equal to "DA_1000". and I managed to do that. But when I trying inserting to the where condition the explicit cell value I can't get any result,

This is the working query:

```
=query({query(A1:F15,"Select * Where E=444",1)},Select * Where Col4='DA_1000',1)
```

This is the non-working query:

```
=query({query(A1:F15,"Select * Where E=444",1)},Select * Where Col4='TEST!N6',1)
```

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oO4mO_KYSFbbP3Q_Jat3NnsUJCfB8u31_LQ8Nmj9D-Q/edit?usp=sharing) is the url for the google sheet.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would want the select-clause in a cell (ex: H10) you'd have to write in this cell:

```
="Select * Where Col4='"&TEST!N6&"'"
```

Then in your query:

```
=query({query(A1:F15,"Select * Where E=444",1)},H10,1)
```

Note that this can also be done in one query by writing in the reference cell

```
=" and D='"&TEST!N6&"'"
```

and then your query would look like this:

```
=query(A1:F15,"Select * Where E=444"&H10,1)
```

Comment: This works, but this was a simplification. In a more complex query, aka: [SELECT P,Q,SUM(R),SUM(S),SUM(T),SUM(R)/SUM(S),SUM(R)/SUM(T),SUM(T)/SUM(S) GROUP BY P,Q order by Q] replacing the the part of the original: query(A1:F15,"Select * Where E=444",1). I can't seem to utilise the same concept

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe*:

```
=query(A:F,"where E=444 and D contains 'DA_1000'")
```

would serve.